# git: where cloned remote repository is saved?

Tags: git

I cloned OpenCV using:

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
```

Now I want to know where is downloaded in order to unpack it. All what I know is: `dpkg -L git`  leads me to this directory: `/usr/lib/`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you've started the clone command you should have get this message:

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
Cloning into 'opencv'...
```

You should find the OpenCV source in a folder named just `opencv` where you launched the `git clone` command.